# Allow text from different cultures in Textbox C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, cultureinfo

I have an application in which username is both in English and Japanese(for Japanese users.)

I am retrieving username from database and want to allow both English and Japanese cultures' username in my text box that displays username.

How to do it?

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing when you are trying to show English and Japanese Culture name in the same box? Is it while showing you are facing the problem or while entering it into the text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property call **ImeMode** for text box which is by default "No control" which allow you to enter both **English and Japanese** 
There is also other options like Hiragana,katagana,Alpha etc...
[image]

And regarding question of comparing string there is no need to worry about it is work with Unicode so it will compare both English and Japanese text.
[image]